# Using GetX binStream with Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I'm working on a food delivery application using Firebase as my backend. And I'm using GetX for state management.

I'm having problems with the firebase streams when trying to retrieve the list of restaurants. As the first image shows, I've written a function returning a Sream<List>. Then when I initialise my controller, I link this function to the stream so that I can listen to my db and any changes that may occur. Unfortunately, I end up with an empty list. It's as if this stream didn't return any restaurants.

What should I do?

```
/ Fetching data from firestore
    Stream<List<RestaurantModel>> getAllRestaurants() {
        return _db.collection("restaurants")
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) {
            return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => RestaurantModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc)).toList();
           });
    }


    // binding my restaurant list to a stream on getX controller initialization
    void onInit() {
        _restaurantList.bindStream(restaurantServices.getAllRestaurants());
        filterRestaurantsByCategory(selectedCategory.value);
        super.onInit();
    }

    // Restaurant Model
    class RestaurantModel {

    late final String uid;
    late final String name;
    late final String category;
    late final String address;
    late final String imagePath;
    late final List<dynamic> menuCategory;

    RestaurantModel({
        required this.uid,
        required this.name,
        required this.category,
        required this.address,
        // required this.rate,
        required this.menuCategory,
        required this.imagePath,
    });

    RestaurantModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot doc){
        uid = doc.id;
        name = doc["name"];
        category = doc["category"];
        address = doc["address"];
        menuCategory = doc["menuCategory"];
            imagePath = doc["imagePath"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document that you expect this code to handle and show?

Comment: ![I wasn't able to upload the screenshot directly. So here's the link that will allow you to access it](https://imgur.com/a/n6w3HT6)

Comment: When I print my **getAllRestaurants** function, I notice that the data has indeed been retrieved from the db. The problem is that I can't get the data into the variable **_restaurantList**.